# Установка флага на всех чекбоксах по нажатию на главный

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Нужно чтобы по клику на один чекбокс, на всех остальных ставилась галочка, а при повторном клике убиралась.

Сделал так (см. ниже), убирать — убирает выделенные, а вот повторно ничего не происходит, что делать?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#check59').click(function(){
         if (document.getElementById('check59').checked == false) { 
            $('input.checks_all7').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            }); 

        } 
         if (document.getElementById('check59').checked == true) {
            $('input.checks_all7').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Все решается гораздо проще, парой строк. Перебирать каждый элемент «руками» нет необходимости. Изучите, как работают селекторы в JQuery.

```js
$('#check59').on('change', function(){
  $('.checks_all7').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Checkboxes</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="check59"> Отметить все</label>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks_all7">
  </p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: чтоб было правильно нужно заменить on('click') на on('change'). Изменить состояние чекбокса можно не только кликом

Comment: @myvzar верно, событие **change** будет более корректным для `<input type="checkbox">`. Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

[JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/siwagohotu)

```js
$('#check59').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('input.checks_all7').each(function() {
      this.checked = true; // свойство отвечает за выделение checkbox-а
    });
  } else {
    $('input.checks_all7').each(function() {
      this.checked = false; // снимаем выделение у всех нужных чекбоксов
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Выделить все
<input type='checkbox' id='check59'>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Немножко изменил твою функцию и все заработало

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check59').click(function(){
         if(document.getElementById('check59').checked==false) { 
            $('input.checks_all7').each(function(){
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }); 

        } 
         if(document.getElementById('check59').checked==true) {
            $('input.checks_all7').each(function(){
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Можно сделать такую функцию и более простым способом [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGezYR?editors=101)

```
<input type='checkbox' id='check59'>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checks_all7'>
```

Html + Js

```
<script>
    $("#check59").click(function () {
        if (!$("#check59").is(":checked")){
            $(".checks_all7").removeAttr("checked");
        }else{
            $(".checks_all7").prop("checked","checked");
            }
    });
</script>
```

Или поискать в гугле: **Как отметить все чекбоксы**